# Java Observer/Observable pattern does not Notify

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swt, observer-pattern

I am trying to build a simple Java application with SWT using the MVC pattern. I would like to be able to automatically update the view when something happens in the background so I am trying to use the Observer/Observable pattern, but it looks like my Observer is never notified when my Observable changes.

Here is the code:

**Launcher.java (main class)**

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        PenguinView v = new PenguinView(app);
        Controller api = new Controller(app, v);
    }

}
```

**Application.java (The background application)**

```
public class Application {
    private Penguin _myPenguin;

    public Application() {
        _myPenguin = new Penguin();
        new Thread(_myPenguin).start();
    }

    public Penguin getPenguin() {
        return _myPenguin;
    }
}
```

**Penguin.java (The model, my Observable)**

```
public class Penguin extends Observable implements Runnable {
    private String _color;
    private boolean _isHappy;
    private int _myRocks;

    public Penguin() {
        _color = "Black";
        _isHappy = true;
        _myRocks = 0;
    }

    public void paint(String color) {
        _color = color;
        System.out.println("My new color is " + _color);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return _color;
    }

    public void upset() {
        _isHappy = false;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void cheerUp() {
        _isHappy = true;
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public boolean isHappy() {
        return _isHappy;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Penguin starts walking and find rocks!
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            iFoundRock();
        }
    }

    private void iFoundRock() {
        _myRocks++;
        System.out.println("I now have " + _myRocks + " rocks");
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

}
```

**PenguinView.java (The SWT View, my observer)**

```
public class PenguinView implements Observer {
    private Application _app;

    private Display _d;
    private Shell _s;

    private Label _penguinColor;
    private Label _penguinHumor;
    private Label _penguinRocks;
    private Button _upset;
    private Button _cheerUp;
    private Text _newColor;
    private Button _paint;


    public PenguinView(Application app) {
        _app = app;
        _d = new Display();
        _s = new Shell();

        RowLayout rl = new RowLayout();
        rl.marginWidth = 12;
        rl.marginHeight = 12;
        _s.setLayout(rl);

        new Label(_s, SWT.BORDER).setText("Penguin Color: ");
        _penguinColor = new Label(_s, SWT.BORDER);
        _penguinColor.setText(_app.getPenguin().getColor());

        new Label(_s, SWT.BORDER).setText(" Humor: ");
        _penguinHumor = new Label(_s, SWT.BORDER);
        String humor = _app.getPenguin().isHappy() ? "Happy" : "Sad";
        _penguinHumor.setText(humor);

        new Label(_s, SWT.BORDER).setText(" Rocks: ");
        _penguinRocks = new Label(_s, SWT.BORDER);
        _penguinRocks.setText(String.valueOf(_app.getPenguin().howManyRocks()));

        _upset = new Button(_s, SWT.PUSH);
        _upset.setText(":(");
        _upset.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                _penguinHumor.setText("Sad");
            }
        });

        _cheerUp = new Button(_s, SWT.PUSH);
        _cheerUp.setText(":)");
        _cheerUp.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                _penguinHumor.setText("Happy");
            }
        });

        _newColor = new Text(_s, SWT.BORDER);

        _paint = new Button(_s, SWT.PUSH);
        _paint.setText("Paint!");
        _paint.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){
            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                //_penguinColor.setText(_newColor.getText());
                _app.getPenguin().paint(_newColor.getText());
            }
        });

        _s.pack();
        _s.open();
        while (!_d.isDisposed()) {
            if (!_d.readAndDispatch()) {
                _d.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    public void update(Observable obs, Object obj) {
        System.out.println("I go here!");
        _penguinRocks.setText(String.valueOf(((Penguin)obs).howManyRocks()));
        if(obs.equals(_app.getPenguin())) {
            _penguinRocks.setText(String.valueOf(((Penguin)obs).howManyRocks()));
        }
    }

    public void update(Observable obs) {
        System.out.println("I go there!");
    }
```

**Controller.java (The controller)**

```
public class Controller {
    Application _app;
    PenguinView _v;

    public Controller(Application app, PenguinView v) {
        _app = app;
        _v = v;

        // Set observer
        _app.getPenguin().addObserver(_v);
    }

}
```

**The output**:

```
I now have 1 rocks
I now have 2 rocks
My new color is Blue
I now have 3 rocks
I now have 4 rocks
```

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: at what point is your view registered as an observer with the Penguin instance? I can't seem to find that LOC (maybe I missed it somewhere...)

Comment: Where is your method notifyObservers()?

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: In the controller's constructor: `_app.getPenguin().addObserver(_v);`

Comment: @talnicolas: In the `iFoundRock()` method of the `Penguin` class

Comment: @talnicolas my guess is that it's implemented in the base class. Not sure in SWT if it needs to be overridden or not.

Comment: @nbarraille ah, sorry, I was looking for it in the view's code.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: Should it be in the View's code from a design standpoint? I thought it made more sense in the Controller as it is the class which is binding everything together. And yes, the `notifyObservers()` is implemented in the `java.util.observable` class. I believe there is no need to override it (but I might be wrong)

Comment: have you tried scoping your `notifyObservers()` calls to the super class?

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Brian Driscoll, @talnicolas: I believe I found the problem: When the PenguinView is created it is blocking the Thread, so the Controller is never created and the View never registered as an observer. I am trying to run the View in a new Thread now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the *while* loop in the **PenguinView** constructor is blocking your main thread, so the **Controller** never gets instantiated and the observer is never added.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. But I have another problem with SWT: As soon as I instantiate my View, the main thread gets stuck in the loop and I can't instantiate my controller (I can't instantiate it before the View because it needs a reference to the View instance)

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem. Have you got the solution please ?

Comment: Don't put infinite loops in your constructor, put them into another method that you call from main().  If that doesn't work put your code in a new question.