# Any simple code samples for Java SWT MVC/other GUI design patterns

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, user-interface, swt

I am new to Java GUI development and am looking for some simple code samples for Java GUI design patterns. I found some like

- [Java Observer/Observable pattern does not Notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537532/java-observer-observable-pattern-does-not-notify)
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html (good but lacking the view code, like the base class etc how other views implements/extend it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Netbeans, use the default "Java Desktop Application" template to generate a skeleton app that'll have several interesting things that you can take a look at. It's based off of [JSR 296](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_Application_Framework).