# Why does this Observer not update when it's running?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I've a class which implements Observer & Runnable as follows (I'm aware this example may be clumsy):

```
public class Triage implements Observer,Runnable{
    Observable obsrvbl;
    private BlockingQueue<String> messages; 
    volatile static boolean interrupted=false;  
    double updated;

    Triage(Observable obsrvbl, BlockingQueue messages){
    this.obsrvbl=obsrvbl;
    this.messages = messages;
    obsrvbl.addObserver(this);
    }

    public void update(Observable o, Object arg){
        updated += ((Double)arg).doubleValue();
        System.out.println("updated");
    }

    public void run(){
        String msg; 
        while(!interrupted){
            msg=messages.take();
            if(msg!=null){    
                //do something with message         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Queue that is being peeked at is populated at the same time that Observable calls notifyObservers(). When there is nothing on the Queue, update() is successfully called on the Observer but if the Queue has messages on it to be processed, update() never gets called. Is this expected behaviour ?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537532/java-observer-observable-pattern-does-not-notify) but it seems to be a different issue.

And here's the Observable - somewhat contrived:

```
public class Producer extends Observable implements Runnable {
    volatile static boolean interrupted=false;
    private BlockingQueue<String> quotes;
    Producer(BlockingQueue quotes){
        this.quotes=quotes; 
    }
    public void run(){
        String msg;     
        while(!interrupted){    
            msg=quotes.take();
            if(msg!=null){
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(Double.valueOf(3.0));   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `setChanged` on the Observable?

Comment: Yes. The Observer gets updated when the Queue isn't populated so the Observable side of things seems ok.

Comment: Note: `if((msg=messages.peek())!=null){ msg=messages.poll();` can be replaced by `msg = messages.take();` to avoid some busy waiting.

Comment: I would use `messages.take()` to wait for the messages, or use an ExecutorService which combines the queue and the thread.  I don't understand what the Observable adds to this. (That you can't do with messages)

Comment: Show us the code for the Observable. Are you certain it's calling `notifyObservers()`?

Comment: Not sure it adds anything - calls setChanged() & notifyObservers(). The point is that update() on the Observer is called successfully if there's nothing on the Queue. Fails only if the Queue is not empty.

Comment: There isn't much in your update() that can fail (I assume if it threw a ClassCastException, you'd see it). Therefore either notifyObservers isn't being called, or notifyObservers is faulty. So we need to see them. I don't see a linkage here between the queue and the Observer/Observable.

Comment: I assume the Observable is running in a different thread to the run() shown here, right?

Comment: Yes - updated the question with the Observable.

Comment: "When there is nothing on the Queue" - which queue? `quotes` or `messages`? Or are they both the same queue?

Comment: also have you tried stepping through the Producer thread with a debugger?

Comment: @slim different queues. Haven't stepped through - logging in detail. Will output more to logs and investigate. Seems like Triage simply ignores the update when it's busy processing messages off the queue (messages).

Comment: I don't go for that explanation. Note that Triage.update() should happen synchronously in the Producer.run() thread.

Comment: Don't be afraid to use spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong with this - oversight on my part. As @slim suggested in a comment the two queues were the same so Triage's run() was consuming the message before Producer's run() and so not being notified. Anyway fwiw - here's a complete working example:

```
public class Triage implements Observer,Runnable{
    Observable obsrvbl;
    private BlockingQueue<String> messages; 
    volatile static boolean interrupted=false;  
    Integer updated = 0;
    private static Random rand = new Random(47);

    Triage(Observable obsrvbl, BlockingQueue messages){
        this.obsrvbl=obsrvbl;
        this.messages = messages;
        obsrvbl.addObserver(this);
    }

    public void update(Observable o, Object arg){
        updated += ((Integer)arg);
        System.out.println("Updated: " + updated);
    }

    public void run(){
        String msg; 
        while(!interrupted){
            try{
                msg=messages.take();
                System.out.println("Run: " + msg);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        BlockingQueue<String> q1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        BlockingQueue<String> q2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        Producer p = new Producer(q1);
        new Thread(p).start();
        new Thread(new Triage(p,q2)).start();
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){      
            int next = rand.nextInt(10)*500;
            System.out.println("Populating: " + next);
            q1.add((Integer.valueOf(next)).toString());
            q2.add((Integer.valueOf(next)).toString());         
        }
    }
}

class Producer extends Observable implements Runnable {
    volatile static boolean interrupted=false;
    private BlockingQueue<String> quotes;
    Producer(BlockingQueue quotes){
        this.quotes=quotes; 
    }
    public void run(){
        String msg;     
        while(!interrupted){    
            try{
                msg=quotes.take();
                if(msg!=null){
                    System.out.println("Notifying: " + msg);
                    setChanged();
                    notifyObservers(Integer.valueOf(msg));  
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
        }
    }
}
```